# Node naming problems

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

There are two machines:
M1 with two ip addresses 192.168.5.47, 192.168.1.250. 
And M2 with ip 192.168.5.250.

I launch an erlang node on M1:

```
nik@nik-PC:~/erlsrc/test_mk$ erl -name 'test@127.0.0.1' -setcookie cook
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V10.6.2  (abort with ^G)
(test@127.0.0.1)1>
```

Then, I'm making another node on M2 and try to ping M1:

```
nik2@nik2-PC:~$ erl -name 'test2@127.0.0.1' -setcookie cook
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V10.6.2  (abort with ^G)
(test2@127.0.0.1)1> 
(test2@127.0.0.1)1> net_adm:ping('test@192.168.5.47').
pang
(test2@127.0.0.1)2>
```

How to make a communication between nodes on remote machines if one of them has several ip addresses and launched as 'name@localhost' or 'name@127.0.0.1'?
Or it's better to use domain names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nodes is running in one LAN Network but one different computers, you can try detect your IP on each of computer, eg run:

```sh
$ hostname -I
```

Let's pretend that **machine 1** has IP `192.168.5.47` and **machine 2** has IP `192.168.5.250`.
Now you ou need run node on **machine 1** with flag `name` what include the IP - **machine #1**:

```sh
$ erl -name 'test@192.168.5.47' -setcookie cook
```

Now do the same in **machine 2**, but use IP of **machine 2** - **machine #2**:

```sh
$ erl -name 'test@192.168.5.250' -setcookie cook
```

Now you can try send `ping` from `test@192.168.5.47` to `test@192.168.5.250` - **machine #1**:

```erlang
(test@192.168.5.47)1> net_adm:ping('test@192.168.5.250').
pong
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. It’s very useful and I used to do this way, but it’s like a hardcode in the node name. What shall we do if I try to connect this node from another sub-network (192.168.1.X)? Because for my example, the machine M1 has two IP aliases for two sub-networks. Or the best way is to use domain names?..

Comment: Yes, you can use domain names if your servers are configured correctly.

Comment: But domain name will be matched with some IP, I suppose you need detect what exactly IP you can use and try to use it. Also, maybe you cannot send `ping` from M1 to M2 by reason that you need do some configuration of server, in this case you can take a look to tool `iptables` - using this tool you can allow access to some port only from a specific IP in computer, since without certain skills to allow full access from all IP's to a computer from outside - can be dangerous.